# float* from C to C#

Tags: c#, c, pointers, malloc, marshalling

I'm not truly a CS guy, so if any of you geniuses on here can point me in the right direction I'll be eternally grateful.

I have a c-code command line function that used to write its results to file.  I converted it to return it's data via a float* array to a C++ program like such (to avoid constant file I/O):

```
float * mgrib(int argc, char **argv)
```

This worked perfectly.  I now need to get this into a C# program, and here's where things go haywire.

The first thing I did to avoid the char ** was to make the arguments a series of bool.  That worked fine if I allow it to still dump to file.

The problem is juggling the c-style float array in C#.  Within the c-code it was allocated with malloc.

So here's everything I've tried with no success(I know the size of the array):

1. Make a "free" function to export to call from C# to release the memory when I'm done with it.  After a few loops the C# crashes with no warning.
2. Release the malloc from C# with Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem.  Same result.
3. Move the float* to an argument and remove the c-code malloc.  (void mgrib(..., float* data,...)

__a)Allocate it with Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem.  Free it with Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem.

__b)Use Marshal.Copy to allocate.  Free it with Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem (Maybe this is wrong?)

I've dabbled in just about everything I could find in the internet.  Please let me know if more info is necessary.  I'm hoping this just a simple concept that I'm missing.

Comment: Forget the C prototype and write a clean one with C#. Return a float array (float[]) instead.

Comment: Please post your c# code

Comment: Are you trying to do this well, or easily? The easy way would be to leave both programs nearly intact, but have the communicate via a pipe instead of a file. To do it well, you're probably better off writing the whole program in one language.

Comment: I'm quite good at c# at this point, but much too weak in c-code to convert the full (very large) program from c to c#.  I do wish that was an option.  I'll try the below suggestion and if that is unsuccessful post some of the c# (It's a pain since the machines are not connected so I would need to sneaker net it), though it's mostly just the Dllimport call within a loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this signature for your C function (replace the `mgrib.dll` with real library name).

```
[DllImport( "mgrib.dll", EntryPoint = "mgrib" )]
public static extern IntPtr mgrib(
    int argc,
    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr )]
    StringBuilder[] argv );
```

Call the `mgrib` function as follows:

```
// Prepare arguments in proper manner
int argc = 0;
StringBuilder[] argv = new StringBuilder[ argc ];
IntPtr pointer = mgrib( argc, argv );
```

When the call is done, you can get the result like this:

```
float[] result = new float[ size ];
Marshal.Copy( pointer, result, 0, size );
```

**EDIT**:

Since the `mgrib` is allocating the memory using `malloc`, we need to free the memory using `free` function. However, you will have to wrap the call to `free` function in another function that will be exported from native library.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void mgrib_free( float* pointer );

void mgrib_free( float* pointer )
{
    free( result );
}
```

And then import it into like this:

```
[DllImport( "mgrib.dll", EntryPoint = "mgrib_free",
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl )]
public static extern void mgrib_free( IntPtr pointer );
```

And invoke it as follows:

```
mgrib_free( pointer );
```

Comment: Rest, Thanks a lot for your detailed reply. This is actually exactly what I did for one of my many attempts. Your answer gave me the confidence to drill down a little deeper and step through each iteration (ugh). I discovered that no matter what the program crashes without warning after accessing 'mgrib' 256 times. That's a little too much of a coincidence. I was using Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem. Marshal.FreeHGlobal throws a handle error. So I think it's pretty clear now that FreeCoTaskMem isn't quite cutting it, somehow the memory isn't being freed. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but before I learned how to use IntPtr.  I'll give it a try.  Thanks for coming back to this.

Comment: Turns out after all that I was cutting off the destruction of another pointer in the c-code when I returned the data I was interested in.  Thanks a lot trying to help me solve my own stupidity ;)!