# Accessing System.Reflection.Pointer from python

Tags: c#, python, .net, system.reflection, python.net

I'm using pythonnet to access functions from a managed dll.
One of the functions in the dll should return a float pointer (float*).
When i call this function with pythonnet, it returns a System.Reflection.Pointer.
Anyone an idea how I could get the actual data (an array of floats) from this pointer in python?

Loading dll:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference(r"C:\Program Files\Thorlabs\Thorlabs OSA\ThorlabsOSAWrapper.dll")
from ThorlabsOSAWrapper import *
```

Calling function from dll:

```
# x_values should be a float* but i get a System.Reflection.Pointer
x_values = spectrum.GetXArray()
```

Comment: have you tried `Marshal.Copy()`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5238483/2230844

Comment: How does one convert a Python List or NumPy Array into a C#-style array, so it can be passed to `Marshall.Copy()`?